# VBA ComboBox Event handling

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, event-handling

I am new to VBA and I am trying to make a dynamic Userform to complete Monte Carlo Simulations with currently I cant get the comboBox event to do anything when changing the item in the list. The code below is the "main" module

```
Dim objMyEventClass As New Class1
Public theComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Sub populateUserform()

'Dim ctl_Command As Control
Dim getInput As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim distribution(5) As String
Dim theLabel As Control
'Dim theComboBox As Control

distribution(1) = "Normal distribution"
distribution(2) = "Discrete distribution"
distribution(3) = "Triangular distribution"
distribution(4) = "Uniform distribution"
distribution(5) = "BETA-Pert distribution"

getInput = Application.InputBox("Enter the number of inputs", , , , , , , 1)

If getInput > 8 Then
    Main.ScrollHeight = (getInput - 8) * 30 + 300
End If

For i = 1 To getInput
    Set theLabel = Main.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & i, True)
        With theLabel
            .Caption = "Test" & i
            .Height = 20
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 50
            .top = 30 * i * 1
        End With
Next i

For i = 1 To getInput
    Set theComboBox = Main.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "combo" & i, True)
        With theComboBox
            .Height = 20
            .Left = 100
            .Width = 100
            .top = 30 * i * 1
        End With
    theComboBox.List = distribution
    
    'ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To i)
    
    'Set cmdArray(i).CmdEvents = theComboBox
    
    'Set theComboBox = Nothing
    Set objMyEventClass.cmdEvents = theComboBox

Next i
End Sub
```

This populates my userform with label I have test values for now and the comboBoxes which contain all different possible distributions. What I need to happen is when a type of distribution is selected it will add more labels and textboxes based on the type of distribution. My class code for the comboBox can be seen below

```
Public WithEvents cmdEvents As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub cmdEvents_click()
If Me.cmdEvents.Value = "Normal distribution" Then
    Call nDist(Me.cmdEvents.top)
ElseIf Me.cmdEvents.Value = "Uniform distribution" Then
    Call uDist(Me.cmdEvents.top)
ElseIf Me.cmdEvents.Value = "Triangular distribution" Then
    Call triDist(Me.cmdEvents.top)
End If

End Sub
```

I have _click right now but have tried _afterUpdate and _change both have the same result

Comment: You have multiple comboboxes but only one instance of `Class1`  ?  You need one instance per combobox, so use a Collection or an array maybe.

Comment: I did that at first but i tried to make it into one class since if the combo box is changed i need to add or remove textboxes and they would be in a completly different class maybe I have to rethink my approach. Or look into calling my clear function across classes